# "Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event handler is already finished," after Request.clone().json()

Tags: javascript, request, clone

In my service worker's 'fetch' listener I want to examine the body of a POST request, and then later do `event.respondWith(fetch(event.request))`. I clone the request and then convert the clone's body to an object, which works fine, but then I get the "event handler is already finished" error from `event.respondWith(fetch(event.request))`. I thought if I cloned the request I was free to read the body of the clone without impacting the original request. How can I examine the request body in the 'fetch' listener and then still fetch the request later?

Here's the service worker:

```
'use strict';

self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
  try {
    const req_obj = await event.request.clone().json();
    console.log(req_obj);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

If I don't clone the request, or if I clone it but I don't call the .json() method of the clone, then everything is fine. Also, I tried `new Request(event.request)` instead of `event.request.clone()`, and I tried first using the constructor to copy the request and then calling the .clone() of that copy, but still I get the same error when finally doing `event.respondWith(fetch(event.request))`;

At https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/clone I read some stuff about backpressure on teed streams and such, which I didn't really understand, and then the warning:

> Beware when you construct a Request from a stream and then clone it.

Does this mean I can't clone my request and then later fetch it?

Comment: You need to pass a promise to `respondWith`, instead of making the entire event handler async. You can try an async IIFE and do the cloning inside of that; `event.respondWith((async () => { /* do the async stuff... */ })())`

Comment: Thanks @vrugtehagel, that was the fix I needed. If you want to make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that calling `event.respondWith` is no longer valid after awaiting the `.json()` call. To resolve this, pass a promise to `event.respondWith` that includes the `.json()` call as well as the `fetch`:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith((async () => {
    try {
      const req_obj = await event.request.clone().json();
      console.log(req_obj);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    return fetch(event.request);
  })());
});
```